# How to use custom transliteration in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents in elastichsearch that are in plain Armenian. I want to configure my search so that I can search not only using Armenian text, but also words written by Latin letters. I found out that I can use `Armenian-Latin/BGN` transliteration using this configuration.

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "armenian_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "armenian_transliterate"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "armenian_transliterate": {
          "type": "icu_transform",
          "id": "Any-Latin; NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC; Armenian-Latin/BGN"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "link": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "text": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "armenian_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, this has a major drawback. Not all the mappings are correct, meaning that people use different mappings most of the time. So I want to do my own mappings, but here comes the second problem. Lot of Latin letters may have multiple possible mappings in Armenian, and vice versa. For example, letter `t` can be both `թ` and `տ` in Armenian, and letter `ե` can be written both as `e` and `ye`. Final note, `ts` can mean single letter `ց`, but also be just a combination of 2 separate letters `թս`. How should I configure the mapping for it?